# Recursive component inclusion

Tags: ractivejs

I'm looking at the [Authoring Ractive.js components](https://github.com/ractivejs/component-spec/blob/master/authors.md) document on github from Rich-Harris.

It starts with invoking the foo component and including it this way:

```html
<link rel='ractive' href='foo.html' name='foo'>
<p>This is an imported 'foo' component: <foo/></p>
```

Which I understand as declaring foo.html as a component and calling it on the foo tag, and this would not require doing a ractive.load (although I did not understand yet where the data loading would occur).

As it does not work at all (no loading of the component), I'm wondering if I mis-understood this part.

Has anyone use this and could give me a complete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components themselves are independent of the loading mechanism.

In the simplest form, components can be declared in javascript:

```
Ractive.components.foo = Ractive.extend({
    template: '#foo' // id of script tag, or can be inline string,
    // other options
});

var ractive = new Ractive({
    template: '<p>This is an main view with a 'foo' component: <foo/></p>'
});
```

Creating components is covered [here](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/components) in the docs.

There are many ways to package and load components. Using the link tag, as in your example, requires using [ractive-load](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive-load) to actually load the components:

```
<!-- name is optional if same as file name -->
<link rel='ractive' href='foo.html' name='foo'> 

<script src='ractive.js'></script>
<script src='ractive-load.js'></script>

<script>

// calling load() with no parameters loads all link tags and 
// registers them as global components
Ractive.load().then( function () {

  var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: 'body',
    template: 'I have access to the <foo/> component!',
    data: { ... }
  });

  // or you could instantiate a component via:
  var app = new Ractive.components.app({
      ... /options
  });
}).catch( handleError );

</script>
```